# How to pass data between not neighbor view controllers in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I've stuck in the problem. 
I have a storyboard with several view controllers.

What I need to do is:
I need to pass an array from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` (they are not neighbors and are not connected via segue) where PikerView will upload the array. After that the picked result should be passed to `ThirdViewController`. 
I have tabbed applicateion where `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewControllers` are connected to Tab Bar View Controller and `ThirdViewController` is connected with `SecondViewController` via Push Segue.

See how I try to pass data form First to Second

**CategoryExpencesViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddCategoryViewController.h"
#import "CategoryPickerViewController.h"
@interface CategoryExpencesViewController : UITableViewController         <AddCategoryViewControllerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *editButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *categories; //list of category items
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listOfCategories; //list of category names
```

**CategoryExpencesViewController.m**

```
-(void)updateArray
{
CategoryPickerViewController *controller = [[CategoryPickerViewController alloc]init];
controller.categoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
controller.categoryList = listOfCategories;
NSLog(@"%d", [listOfCategories count]);
NSLog(@"%d", [controller.categoryList count]);

}
```

Comment: Put the data in a model object.  Tell the view controllers about the model object.  Use a bit of KVO to detect changes.

Comment: Pls tell me more about model object. I'm new to Objective C so miss knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: Search for MVC on the Apple Developer website; you will get *many* hits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue%3asender%3a)

Use your's Push Segue.

`segue.sourceViewController` (or self) will point at `SecondViewController`.
`segue.sourceViewController.tabBarController` will point at Tab Bar Controller.

From Tab Bar Controller you will find your's `FirstViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would have solved it, but i post this just for the record:

Wrap the array into a class, and make it have a static construction method:

Wrapper.h:

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* array;
    +(Wrapper*)createArray;
```

Wrapper.m:

```
    +(Wrapper*)createArray{
        static Wrapper* instance = nil;
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[Wrapper alloc] init];
            //Your initialization code for the array
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Then, in your FirstViewController:

```
    -(void)updateArray{
        CategoryPickerViewController *controller = [[CategoryPickerViewController alloc]init];
        controller.categoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        controller.categoryList = [[Wrapper createArray] array];
        NSLog(@"%d", [listOfCategories count]);
        NSLog(@"%d", [controller.categoryList count]);

    }
```

As this is the first call to Wrapper, the array is generated.
Then in your SecondViewController, when you call:

```
    secondView.categoryList = [[Wrapper createArray] array];
```

and you obtain the same array as in FirstViewcontroller.

Answer (score -2):

have you thought of NSUserDefault try it and you can also create a instance global variable in AppDelegate class and access it by creating an instance of AppDelegate in any other ViewController but i think NSUserDefault is the best option from all.